# Using UTF-8 in Jtwig with translation property-files

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, internationalization, jtwig

I have 4 locales in my resources folder which I'm loading exactly as shown in this example: https://github.com/jtwig/jtwig-examples/blob/master/gradle-jtwig-translate-extension-properties/src/main/java/org/jtwig/example/translate/SimpleAppWithTranslate.java

However the properties are not loaded with the correct encoding.

E.g. the German `Grüsse` from the property file becomes `GrÃ¼sse` once loaded via Jtwig's `PropertiesLocalizedMessageResourceLoader`. It happens in this part of the example code:

```
propertiesMessageSource()
  .withLookupClasspath("translations")
  .build()
```

Is there an easy way to load the property files in UTF-8 using something like the code from the link above?

P.S. I'm using Java 11

Comment: You can't, because properties files are required to be encoded in **ISO 8859-1** as specified in the [javadoc of Properties.read(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-)

Comment: You need to use escaping in properties file, e.g. `Gr\u00FCe` instead of `Grüsse`.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch thanks, that's what I'm currently doing as a work-around, I was hoping I could avoid that.

Comment: Linking the ISO 8859-1 character list here for reference: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/ISO-8859-1/list.htm

Comment: This tool can convert native characters to ascii: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html